# This function is not production quality, how can I make it more robust?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, memory, .net-core

.NET CORE 2.1, C# 7.2 are required for this code.

```
private const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 512;
```

---

```
        var buffer = new Memory<byte>(new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH]); // Allocate 512 byte buffer

        var count = await ReadFromUrlAsync("https://www.microsoft.com", buffer).ConfigureAwait(false); // Gets first 512 bytes of HTML body from web, just random text to fill the buffer
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes: {0}" + Environment.NewLine, count);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(capacity: BUFFER_LENGTH);
        foreach (var val in buffer.ToArray()) // I think I just allocated memory here, can I do this with something more like pointer arithmetic?
        {
            sb.Append((char)val); // I feel like this operation would cause a lot of copying and allocation, am I wrong?
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb); // Perhaps there's a way to do this without StringBuilder?
```

Please note the comments in the code above.

From the perspective of what I'm trying to accomplish here, the main purpose of using the new Span of T types is to avoid additional memory allocation when possible. Is there a more robust and/or low level way to convert the byte Span into a char[]/string aside from cast copying each element into a StringBuilder?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more fit for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Alejandro In the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close questions. Evaluate the request & use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Flag it for Mod intervention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750/1575353). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I'm asking for a way to optimize the code, this is not an opinion, there are three memory allocations in this function, it seems likely it can be optimized to use only two allocations, however, I don't know how to do it. Someone who is more senior and more familiar with the framework should be able to answer this question objectively.

Comment: Additionally, the one answer to this question is exactly the right answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the StringBuilder and foreach with [UTF8Encoding.GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.getstring?view=netcore-2.2)

Comment: Optimized code:
```            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);

            if (convert)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(utf8.GetString(buffer.ToArray()));
            }```

Thank you for your perfect response!